# Get result from async javascript method without callbacks

Tags: javascript, c#, asynchronous

I have javascript function which uses CefSharp.ChroniumBrowser (WinForms).
I registered "jsObject" as script object for browser: Browser.RegisterJsObject(new JsObject()). 
C# code:

```
public class JsObject
{
   //...
  public async void IsServerConnected(IJavascriptCallback callback)
  {
      var result = await Server.GetConnectionResult();
      callback.ExecuteAsync(result);
  }
}
```

The following js code calls C# method which asynchronously checks whether server is connected and executes callback with result.

```
function isServerConnected(callback) {
   window.jsObject.isServerConnected(function (connected) {
      callback(connected);
   });
}
```

and to get the result I should write:

```
isServerConnected(function(result) {
   if (result) {
      // server is connected. do something
   } else {
      // show error
   }
});
```

I would like to get the result in such a way:

```
var result = isServerConnected();
if (result){
  ...
} else {
 ...
}
```

Is it possible to make this work? Maybe promises should help but how I can get the result without using callbacks in the ending call: var result = isServerConnected(); ?

Comment: This feels like it's an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - why do you want it to be a synchronous call - usually async/callbacks are the way to go in JS.  Promises sort of just hide the callbacks away a little - it's still an async call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS code doesn't execute synchronously when we use asynchronous calls. JS is very transparent on synchronous and asynchronous calls. If you are not liking callbacks, with `Promises` introduced in ES6, you have a better way of handling asynchronous calls. Take a look at the following code

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   window.jsObject.isServerConnected(function(connected) {
      resolve(connected);
   });
});
promise.then(function(result) {
   if(result) {
      // server is connected. do something
   } else {
      // show error
   }
}).catch(function(error) {
   // catch all errors here
});
```

Many browsers are not yet added support for `Promises`. Check the browsers compatibility [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). In ES7, we have `async/await`, which will work as you expected. Again, it is not yet added by many browsers. Check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) for more on `async/await`.

Comment: I will try to use async/await if it is supported in the latest version of Cef Chronium Browser. Thanks for ideas!

Comment: FYI, I removed arrow functions in the code as it is not yet supported by some browsers.